# Open Windows Form with opcv From wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, opencv

**note** I am new in Wpf >
I have project that decode qr code by using opencv library throw web cam >
and it running successfully

now I wanna to using this project in new Wpf project >
after adding new wpf project and make reference to WinForms application >

and this my simple code to open WinForm >

```
public void runnow(){
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new CameraCapture.cameraCapture()); }
```

by ruining give me this exception  >

The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.>

what can I do for solve this

C# code

```
 public partial class CameraCapture : Form
 {
 
Capture capture;
    bool Capturing;
    Bitmap bimap;
    private Reader reader;
    private Hashtable hint;
    libAES libEncryption = new libAES();
    string Mykey = "";
   public static String dataDecrypted="";


    public CameraCapture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Mains(object sender, EventArgs arg) // Start function main to encode Qr code
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> image = capture.QueryFrame();
        if (image != null)
        {
            bimap = image.ToBitmap();
            pictureBox1.Image = bimap;
            reader = new QRCodeReader();
            hint = new Hashtable();   //  Add some elements to the hash table. There are no  duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
            hint.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
            RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bimap, bimap.Width, bimap.Height);  //This class is used to help decode images from files which arrive as RGB data from* Android bitmaps. It does not support cropping or rotation.
            BinaryBitmap img = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));
            Result result = null;
            try
            {
                result = reader.decode(img, hint);
                dataDecrypted = libEncryption.Decrypt(result.Text, Mykey);
                
            }
            catch
            {
                dataDecrypted = "";
            }
            if (result == null)
            {
                label1.Text = " no decode";
               
            }
            else
            {

                label4.Text = result.Text;
                label1.Text = dataDecrypted;
              
                capture.Dispose();
                 
            }
        }


    } // end function Main


    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture(); // **the exption thown here**
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }
        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (Capturing)
            {
                btnStart.Text = "Start Capture";
                Application.Idle -= Mains;
            }
            else
            {
                btnStart.Text = "Stop Capture";
                Application.Idle += Mains;
            }
            Capturing = !Capturing;
        }
    }
    private void Release()
    {
        if (capture != null)
            capture.Dispose();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host WinForm in WPF, you need to use host control System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost

> WPF provides many controls with a rich feature set. However, you may
>   sometimes want to use Windows Forms controls on your WPF pages. For
>   example, you may have a substantial investment in existing Windows
>   Forms controls, or you may have a Windows Forms control that provides
>   unique functionality.

Example code

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
// Create the interop host control.
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
    new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

// Create the MaskedTextBox control.
MaskedTextBox mtbDate = new MaskedTextBox("00/00/0000");

// Assign the MaskedTextBox control as the host control's child.
host.Child = mtbDate;

// Add the interop host control to the Grid
// control's collection of child controls.
this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
}
```

Check =>
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx

Comment: same thing >
**The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception**

Comment: Where have you added your Winform component into System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost ?